# shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier issue

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I tried too much to solve my bellow issue but i am failed.Please help me to solve this issue. I have login view and after validating id and password i am pushing it to next view controller.Please check bellow image.
 [image]

Issue - When Id and Password is correct it's pushing to next view controller but after 2 clicks on login button.

Code -

ServiceManager.m

```
 -(void)initGetAppServiceRequestWithUrl:(NSString *)baseUrl onCompletion:  
 (ServiceCompletionHandler)handler
 {
     NSString *fullUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[baseUrl 
            stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL 
            URLWithString:fullUrl]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
         completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,NSData *data,NSError *error)
   {
     if (error) {
         handler(nil,error);
        // NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
    }
     else
     { handler(data, nil);
       // NSLog(@"data = %@",data);
     }
  }];

}
```

JSONResponseHandler.m

```
 +(void)handleResponseData:(NSData *)responseData onCompletion:(JSONHandler)handler
 {
     if (responseData) {
         NSError *jsonParseError;
         NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
         options:kNilOptions error:&jsonParseError];
         if (!json) {
             handler(nil , jsonParseError);
         }
        else
        {
             handler (json , nil);
        }  
    }
}
```

ASKevrServiceManager.m

```
 -(void)login:(Login *)login completionHandler:(ServiceCompletionHandler)handler
 {
     NSString *loginUrl = [NSString    
     stringWithFormat:@"http://249development.us/johnsan/askever/login.php?
     login=%@&password=%@",login.emailAddr , login.password];
     [self initGetAppServiceRequestWithUrl:loginUrl onCompletion:^(id object, NSError 
      *error)
     {
        handler(object , error);
     }
    ];
  }
```

ASKevrOperationManager.m

```
  +(void)login:(Login *)login handler:(OperationHandler)handler
  {
       ASKevrServiceManager *serviceManager = [[ASKevrServiceManager alloc]init];
      [serviceManager login:login completionHandler:^(id object, NSError *error)
      {
          [JSONResponseHandler handleResponseData:object onCompletion:^(NSDictionary 
           *json , NSError *jsonError)
          {
            if(json)
            {
                handler(json , nil , YES);
             }
            else
            {
               handler(nil , jsonError , NO);
            }
        }];
    }];
 }
```

LoginViewController.m

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"pushTab"])
   {
     if ([emailTxt.text isEqualToString:@""] || [passwordTxt.text 
     isEqualToString:@""])
     {
       [self showAlertWithMessage:@"Please write your id or password"];
       return NO;
  }
 else
 {
    Login *loginModel = [[Login alloc]init];
    loginModel.emailAddr =emailTxt.text;
    loginModel.password = passwordTxt.text;
    [ASKevrOperationManager login:loginModel handler:^(id object , NSError *error , 
    BOOL success)
     {
         if (success)
         {
             NSLog(@"object =%@",object);
             NSDictionary *arr = [object objectForKey:@"response"];
             str = [arr objectForKey:@"flag"];
             //check for error
                 NSDictionary *toDict = [object objectForKey:@"response"];
                 currentUserId = [toDict objectForKey:@"c_id"];
                 NSLog(@"currentUserId = %@",currentUserId);
         }
         else
         {
             [self showAlertWithMessage:@"Wrong Id or Password."];
         }
     }];
    NSLog(@"str = %@",str);
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
       // [self showAlertWithMessage:@"Wrong Id or Password."];
        return YES;
    }
   }
 }
return NO;
}
```

Comment: @what is the issue? can you elaborate on thatr

Comment: Surely any authentication view controller should be popped as soon as the user has successfully authenticated; it shouldn't be presenting further view controllers, given it may be called at any time to re-authenticate?

Comment: @trojanfoe : Actually i found error at one place -"initGetAppServiceRequestWithUrl:" first this method is called and after that i am getting JSON object.But When i am clicking at first time with valid authentication it's not sending JSON object and when i am clicking second time with same authentication it's sending JSON as well as calling push segue.

Comment: @meda : I already put one line with name "Issue".Please check it.

Comment: @chaaruu did you attach the segue directly to the button? you shouldnt, also login sould not be part of the navigation

Comment: @meda : yes..But without direct segue if I will try to push it's opening black view.

Answer (score 0):

When pressing login button do run the code

```
if (![emailTxt.text isEqualToString:@""] &&
    ![passwordTxt.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    Login *loginModel = [[Login alloc]init];
    loginModel.emailAddr =emailTxt.text;
    loginModel.password = passwordTxt.text;
    [ASKevrOperationManager login:loginModel handler:^(id object , NSError *error , 
    BOOL success)
     {
         if (success){
             NSLog(@"object =%@",object);
             NSDictionary *arr = [object objectForKey:@"response"];
             str = [arr objectForKey:@"flag"];
             //check for error
                 NSDictionary *toDict = [object objectForKey:@"response"];
                 currentUserId = [toDict objectForKey:@"c_id"];
                 NSLog(@"currentUserId = %@",currentUserId);

            //perform the segue only when succesful
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:sender];
         }else{
            [self showAlertWithMessage:@"Wrong Id or Password."];
         }
     }];    
}else {
    [self showAlertWithMessage:@"Please write your id or password"];
}
```

Keep your `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` simple

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"pushTab"])
   {
        //don't put logic here
        //put code here only if you need to pass data
        //to the next screen
        return YES:
   }
   return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Media , i already tried this but the problem is in my URL calling method. Every time I need to call my "ServiceOperation"method on previous view because it's calling it's functionality after calling all the lines.So, in above code my "str" variable is not getting value at first time and next time it's saving value from previous object..That's why it's taking 2 clicks but i am not able to solve this issue.Can you help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I am not sure I understand really, what is the use of `str` ?