# How do i stop/cancel the segue when UIAlertView triggered

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, segue

I got a button that leads to a `tableViewController`.

I created `UIAlertView` that gets triggered when the **resultArray** is **null**, which also means there is nothing to show on tableView but when user clicks ok, nothing changes and it goes to empty tableView.

How can I stop going into the other view controller?

this is my code

```
 if (refilteredArray.count==0) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No result"
                                                    message:@"Please enter a different combination."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

The segue is not triggered with code, its a button triggered IBAction

```
- (IBAction)motorButton:(id)sender {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following method

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

in the method body you can verify if your array is empty or not and if it is return NO. To be more specyfic you should check your segue identifier (remember to add it to your segue in IB first)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go for `if`.. `else` block

```
if (refilteredArray.count==0) {
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No result"
                                                    message:@"Please enter a different combination."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}else{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:sender];

}
```

For more info, [check this link about segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341947/shouldperformseguewithidentifier-issue)

Comment: well thats the problem, 

its an 
- (IBAction)motorButton:(id)sender {

its not triggered with code

Comment: Just put this code in the IBAction and delete the segue at storyboard. Just do it by programmatically

Comment: how do i set a connection without the direct connection from storyboard

how can i accomplish that