# How to make shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier to wait until block finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a created a push segue and named the identifier to something like "CustomIdentifier". After user signed up successfully, the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier executes and push to another view controller. How to make the push action wait until the user sign up block return success and then execute the push action? What I am doing right now is like below but the push is executed no matter the sign up is not success. What's the better solution to this? By the way, I know I can create a IBAction, but I am using RBStoryboardLink, so it has to be a push segue. and IBAction is not working with RBStoryboardLink.

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    __block BOOL should;
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Question"]) {
        AVUser *newUser = [AVUser user];
        newUser.username = self.usernameField.text;
        newUser.password = self.passwordField.text;
        newUser.email = self.emailField.text;

        [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded) {
                should = YES;
            } else {
                should = NO;
            }
        }];
    }
    return should;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341947/shouldperformseguewithidentifier-issue

Comment: @Rushabh It seems there is no accepted answer.

Comment: that is what you cannot do without blocking the main thread. you probably need to collect that information _before_ your method is invoked.

Comment: @holex is correct. Perform the `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` and only then execute the segue if that succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` at the point where you want to perform segue. In this way, you will only call for a segue when IT IS actually required.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegue" sender:nil];
```

The `prepareForSegue` method will be called immediately after this method is called. In `prepareForSegue` you can write the code that you want to execute before performing the segue.
Something like setting variable value or transferring other data etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know performSegueWithIdentifier. Because I didn't add a IBAction to this bar button item, only a push segue. So, where should I call this performSegueWithIdentifier method? In shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier?

Comment: in your block!.. when you want to do it, at the end of the block

Comment: You need to wire the button to an IBAction which does the login and then performs a 'manual' segue.

Comment: @yong ho, what Mike said is absolutely right. You just have to wire and IBAction event and just use this function at the point where you want to transit to the next view using segue.

Comment: I already knew this. You guys can check my question. Because i am using rbstoryboardlink to push another storyboard. So how to perform a manual segue using rbstoryboardlink?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1: Maybe you should opt for:**

1. Letting your login coude (in the block) send `NSNotifications` using `NSNotificationCenter` on login and login success.

   ```
   [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
       if (succeeded) {
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoginSuccess" object:self];
       } else {
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"LoginFailure" object:self];
       }
   }];
   ```
2. Register for these notifications on `NSNotificationCenter` when the view controller is loaded.

   ```
   - (void)viewDidAppear
   {
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] void)addObserver:self selector:@selector(loginSuccess:) name:@"LoginSuccess" object:nil]
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] void)addObserver:self selector:@selector(loginFailure:) name:@"LoginFailure" object:nil]
   }
   ```
3. In the action method (`- (void)loginSuccess:(NSNotification *)notification`), that gets notified when the login-success notification is send, you call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier" sender:self]`.
4. In the action method `- (void)loginFailure:(NSNotification *)notification`, that is called on a failure-notification, you might display an alertview or unblock UI (if it was blocked before to have the user not clicking about).

...with your method as such, I would use a dispatch group like:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_group_t dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();
    dispatch_group_enter(dispatchGroup);

    __block BOOL should;
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Question"]) {
        AVUser *newUser = [AVUser user];
        newUser.username = self.usernameField.text;
        newUser.password = self.passwordField.text;
        newUser.email = self.emailField.text;

        [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (succeeded) {
                should = YES;
            } else {
                should = NO;
            }
            // leave group to signal end of processing
            dispatch_group_leave(dispatchGroup);
        }];
    }

    // wait until processing has finished
    dispatch_group_wait(dispatchGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    return should;
}
```

Comment: If should equals to NO, the UI is not responsive, it's frozen. What needs to be done?

Comment: Maybe you are blocking the UI until login success. If so, ensure unblocking it as well when login-failure happens. Edited my post to give a nother option which might be more "transparent" in meanings of design and behaviour.